# How do I find the sum of rolling quarter revenues in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I've coded on a flat data and got the best result. Now I want to find the sum of rolling four quarters revenue.

Data set:

```
Symbol Date Quarter Type Revenue
---------------------------------
A1 12/31/2018 4q2018 x1 5000
B1 12/31/2018 4q2018 x2 2000
C1 12/31/2018 4q2018 x3 3500
D1 12/31/2018 4q2018 x4 2000
A1 09/30/2018 3q2018 x1 1000
B1 09/30/2018 3q2018 x2 2000
C1 09/30/2018 3q2018 x3 1500
D1 09/30/2018 3q2018 x4 2500
A1 06/30/2018 2q2018 x1 1000
B1 06/24/2018 2q2018 x2 4000
C1 06/30/2018 2q2018 x3 1000
D1 06/30/2018 2q2018 x4 2000
A1 03/31/2018 1q2018 x1 1000
B1 01/28/2018 1q2018 x2 4000
C1 02/21/2018 1q2018 x3 1000
D1 03/31/2018 1q2018 x4 2500
A1 12/31/2017 4q2017 x1 1000
B1 12/31/2017 4q2017 x2 2000
C1 12/31/2017 4q2017 x3 1500
D1 12/31/2017 4q2017 x4 2500
```

Expected output:

```
5th row: A1 4q2018 x1 8000 (sum of previous 4 quarters)
6th row: A1 4q2018 x1 12000 (sum of previous 4 quarters)
7th row: A1 4q2018 x1 7500 (sum of previous 4 quarters)
8th row: A1 4q2018 x1 9000 (sum of previous 4 quarters)
```

The same thing after 4 more records

```
13th row: A1 3q2018 x1 4000 (sum of 3q, 2q, 1q 2018 and 4q 2017)
```

Comment: You need to add more details like sample data with expected output, and show us what you have tried?

Comment: Hi, this is very poor information... Please try to add a [mcve] with sample data and the expected output. Btw: v2008 is running out soon, you might [read this](https://community.connection.com/windows-sql-server-2008-2008-r2-end-life-coming-soon-now/).

Comment: What does it mean by ''rolling four quarters ''?

Comment: Added more information.

Comment: Your dates are wrong too I believe. 4q2017 should be 12/31/2017. Not 2018

Comment: I’ve corrected it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to use the `OVER` clause. Probably something like

```
select Symbol, [Quarter], SUM(Revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY Symbol
                                     ORDER BY [Date]
                                     ROWS 4 PRECEDING) AS total
```

Pay around with that and I think you'll come to something close. Also read the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: There was a little issue in your query, see my answer for that, Preceding rows should be 3 and record is ordered by date

Answer (score 1):

A little change in above code by `Sean`, while his code add all rows this corrects the issue:

```
CREATE TABLE #t (Symbol varchar(5),Date datetime,Quarter varchar(10),Type varchar(2),Revenue int)
GO
INSERT INTO #t (Symbol,Date,Quarter,Type,Revenue) VALUES('A1','12/31/2018','4q2018','x1',5000)
INSERT INTO #t (Symbol,Date,Quarter,Type,Revenue) VALUES('B1','12/31/2018','4q2018','x2',2000)
INSERT INTO #t (Symbol,Date,Quarter,Type,Revenue) VALUES('C1','12/31/2018','4q2018','x3',3500)
INSERT INTO #t (Symbol,Date,Quarter,Type,Revenue) VALUES('D1','12/31/2018','4q2018','x4',2000)
INSERT INTO #t (Symbol,Date,Quarter,Type,Revenue) VALUES('A1','09/30/2018','3q2018','x1',1000)
INSERT INTO #t (Symbol,Date,Quarter,Type,Revenue) VALUES('B1','09/30/2018','3q2018','x2',2000)
INSERT INTO #t (Symbol,Date,Quarter,Type,Revenue) VALUES('C1','09/30/2018','3q2018','x3',1500)
INSERT INTO #t (Symbol,Date,Quarter,Type,Revenue) VALUES('D1','09/30/2018','3q2018','x4',2500)
INSERT INTO #t (Symbol,Date,Quarter,Type,Revenue) VALUES('A1','06/30/2018','2q2018','x1',1000)
INSERT INTO #t (Symbol,Date,Quarter,Type,Revenue) VALUES('B1','06/24/2018','2q2018','x2',4000)
INSERT INTO #t (Symbol,Date,Quarter,Type,Revenue) VALUES('C1','06/30/2018','2q2018','x3',1000)
INSERT INTO #t (Symbol,Date,Quarter,Type,Revenue) VALUES('D1','06/30/2018','2q2018','x4',2000)
INSERT INTO #t (Symbol,Date,Quarter,Type,Revenue) VALUES('A1','03/31/2018','1q2018','x1',1000)
INSERT INTO #t (Symbol,Date,Quarter,Type,Revenue) VALUES('B1','01/28/2018','1q2018','x2',4000)
INSERT INTO #t (Symbol,Date,Quarter,Type,Revenue) VALUES('C1','02/21/2018','1q2018','x3',1000)
INSERT INTO #t (Symbol,Date,Quarter,Type,Revenue) VALUES('D1','03/31/2018','1q2018','x4',2500)
INSERT INTO #t (Symbol,Date,Quarter,Type,Revenue) VALUES('A1','12/31/2017','4q2017','x1',1000)
INSERT INTO #t (Symbol,Date,Quarter,Type,Revenue) VALUES('B1','12/31/2017','4q2017','x2',2000)
INSERT INTO #t (Symbol,Date,Quarter,Type,Revenue) VALUES('C1','12/31/2017','4q2017','x3',1500)
INSERT INTO #t (Symbol,Date,Quarter,Type,Revenue) VALUES('D1','12/31/2017','4q2017','x4',2500)

--SELECT * FROM #t WHERE Symbol = 'B1' ORDER BY Date Desc
select Symbol, [Quarter], SUM(Revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY Symbol
                                     ORDER BY [Date]
                                     ROWS 3 PRECEDING) AS total,Date
FROM #t
ORDER BY Date Desc
```

Here is another update for sql server 2008:

```
    select a.Symbol, a.[Quarter], x.Rev,a.Date
FROM #t a 
CROSS APPLY (   SELECT ISNULL(SUM(re), 0) Rev
                    FROM (  SELECT TOP(4) b.Revenue re
                            FROM #t b
                            WHERE b.Symbol = a.Symbol and Convert(varchar,b.Date,112) <= Convert(varchar,a.Date,112)
                            ORDER BY b.Date DESC ) v
                ) x
ORDER BY a.Date Desc

    DROP TABLE #t
```

Comment: So you just copied my answer?

Comment: You can say that, I just did not wanted to edit yours, but anyways I was going to write it similar what else

Comment: Does SQL Server 2008 support "preceding"?